# Different window's border color using NCurses

Tags: colors, window, ncurses

I have couple of NCurses windows running in terminal. Is it possible to set other border color for each window? I tried code below, but it doesn't work:

```
start_color()
// ...

init_pair (1, COLOR_RED, COLOR_CYAN);
attron (COLOR_PAIR (1));
box (window, 0,0);
wrefresh (window);
attroff (COLOR_PAIR (1));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can set a COLOR_PAIR for the entire window like this:

```
wbkgd(WINDOW* your_window,COLOR_PAIR(nb_of_you_pair))
```

For setting color for the box only do:

```
wattron(win,COLOR_PAIR)
box(win,0,0)
wattroff(win,COLOR_PAIR)
```